# How to fix updating inventory items qty?

Tags: python

I have an inventory program, options 1-2 work and so does option 4. The current problem is option 3. It correctly update the item qty if the update is addition. But if the qty is subtraction it does not subtract, it does addition instead. To duplicate my error type 1, type in Apple, qty 10(adding item/qty to inventory), type 98, then 3(Update), type -4, type 98, then 4(retype the item name and it will print the item name and the wrong qty).

How do I fix this?

Full Code:

```
import os


name = []

qty = []

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, name, qty):
        self.name = name
        self.qty = qty

def menuDisplay():
    print ('=============================')
    print ('= Inventory Management Menu =')
    print ('=============================')
    print ('(1) Add New Item to Inventory')
    print ('(2) Remove Item from Inventory')
    print ('(3) Update Inventory')
    print ('(4) Search Item in Inventory')
    print ('(5) Print Inventory Report')
    print ('(99) Quit')
    CHOICE = int(input("Enter choice: "))
    menuSelection(CHOICE)

def menuSelection(CHOICE):

    if CHOICE == 1:
        print('Adding Inventory')
        print('================')
        new_name = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        name.append(new_name)
        new_qty = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item: "))
        qty.append(new_qty)
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
        menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 2:
        print('Removing Inventory')
        print('==================')
        removing = input('Enter the item name to remove from inventory: ')
        indexdel = name.index(removing)
        name.pop(indexdel)
        qty.pop(indexdel)
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
        menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 3:
        print('Updating Inventory')
        print('==================')
        item = input('Enter the item to update: ')
        update = int(input("Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))
        if update <= -1:
            qty[name.index(item)] -= update
            print("Update made")
            CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
            if CHOICE == 98:
                menuDisplay()
            elif CHOICE == 99:
                exit()
        elif update >= 0:
            qty[name.index(item)] += update
            print("Update Made")
            CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
            if CHOICE == 98:
                menuDisplay()
            elif CHOICE == 99:
                exit()
    elif CHOICE == 4:
        print('Searching Inventory')
        print('===================')
        search = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        pos = name.index(search) if search in name else -1
        if (pos >= 0):
            print ('Item:     ', name[pos])
            print ('Quantity: ', qty[pos])
            print ('----------')
        else:
            print("Item not in inventory")
    CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
            menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 5:
        print('Current Inventory')
        print('=================')
        input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
        menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
        printInventory()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()

menuDisplay()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `update` is negative, subtracting it from `qty[name.index(item)]` will increase the quantity, since subtracting a negative number is the same as addition. Just add it instead, like you do for the positive case.